# Can "tmux load-buffer" specify a session?

Tags: tmux

The `tmux paste-buffer` command can specify a session using the `-t` option:

```
tmux paste-buffer -b buffer-name -t session-name:window
```

But `tmux load-buffer` has no `-t` option:

```
tmux load-buffer [-b buffer-name] path
```

If you pass something like `session-name:buffer-name` to the `-b` option, it simply treats "`session-name:buffer-name`" as the buffer name.

I want to load a buffer in a tmux session from outside the session, and if there's more than one session running I want to specify which one.

Is there a (clean) way to do this?

(I suppose that setting the `$TMUX` environment variable would be a solution, but (a) it's not exactly clean, and (b) I haven't figured out how to get the appropriate value for the desired session.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffers are global and do not belong to a particular session so there is no way to specify a session to `load-buffer`. You can name the buffers whatever you want so you could use a form that includes the session name.

Comment: Which means I can copy from one session and paste in another (just confirmed experimentally). I hadn't realized that, since I usually only run a single session. I just wanted to be sure some new stuff I was doing would work in the presence of multiple sessions. Thanks!